# Call to undefined function password_hash() in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I am trying to use the `password_hash()` function in my website, and I am getting an error `Call to undefined function password_hash().` I checked my Server Details in GoDaddy, and my current version of php is 5.4. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need PHP 5.5 for it to work. Use the compatibility pack => https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Answer (score 8):

[`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is not available in PHP 5.4. It is a new feature in PHP 5.5. In the meantime you can use [**this compatibility pack replacement**](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Compatibility pack sidenote:

This library requires PHP >= 5.3.7 OR a version that has the $2y fix backported into it (such as RedHat provides). Note that Debian's 5.3.3 version is NOT supported.

For versions not covered by these versions, consult:

- http://php.net/crypt - (PHP 4, PHP 5)

Comment: I am getting slow in my old age. :O

Comment: +1 Oh, you're not so bad John. I just had my files ready beforehand ;-)

Comment: Guess you've seen this one before? ;)

Comment: Yes John, I saw a question a few weeks ago actually on a similar subject where the SQL was updated at the same time which caused the OP some major headaches and password storage was also mentioned. It's good to remember things like these and to share the wealth, as it were.